# iOS | loading images based on unique file name

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have almost 5000 pictures of products which the company sell, each picture has a name of unique identifier which is the same unique identifier of the product in db.
I want to view the pic of the product inside my program, the problem is ios doesn't help me to deal with the names of the pics so that I can link each product with its picture. There's a solution where I fetch the pic from http server and load it then inside a view, but I need to reduce the traffic and be able to work offline.

any suggestions or scenarios to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "ios doesn't help me to deal with the names of the pics so that I can link each product with its picture" ?

Comment: in ios you deal with assets using AlAsset, asset has a unique id (or link) so you can retrieve the pic using it, correct me if I'm wrong, that's what I discovered.

Comment: Why don't you bundle them with your app?

Comment: There are more than 5000 of them man!! almost 1 Gb!!

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution here is to distribute your application **without images**. When user start to explore products from your app, app should **download images of needed products and cache these images on device**. Next time when user try to look at products, he or she will get cached images.

For offline work app will use cached images and a standart placeholder image for products that has no been viewed before. Also, you can select the most viewed for example 5% of products and include these products' images to the application bundle (Pareto principle - 80/20 - rules).